# Frozen Python Application with cx_Freeze is very slow to start

Tags: python, windows, dll, cx-freeze

I have a fairly complex python application that uses numpy, pandas, PySide, pyqtgraph, and matplotlib, among other packages. When I bundle the application with cx_Freeze on Windows, it comes in at 349MB.

My problem is the resulting executable has a very long startup time of about 15 seconds. When I say startup time, I mean the amount of time before any code gets executed. I have a simple script that prints "Hello" to the console, and even that takes about 15 seconds to run.

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem, or any ways to debug it? Is it slow because there are so many .dll files from so many packages?

EDIT:
Using a great tool called [Process Montor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), I have narrowed down my problem to the pytz module. On one particular load, 20 seconds were spent querying the library.zip (where cx_Freeze puts all of the compiled bytecode) for pytz zoneinfo! I recently added pandas as a dependency, and pandas uses pytz.

See this picture for a sampling of the Process Monitor output:
[image: Redacted identifying info with a blueish rectangle]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution I found is to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see if cx_Freeze is loading a module for an unreasonable amount of time. Using that tool, I also found that it was taking a long time (maybe 4 seconds) to load a particular matplotlib font. I removed it and my application worked fine.

Comment: Any idea on which font it was?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember. I removed matplotlib as a dependency and switched to pyqtgraph, so it solved my problem.

Comment: I had the same problem with pytz and the solution was to take it out of the library.zip (using excludes option) and place it directly next to the exe. This achieved a tenfold speedup.

Comment: I had a similar issue with `pytz`.  `pytz` uses `pkg_resources` (part of `setuptools`) to access the `zoneinfo`.  Old versions of `pkg_resources` appear to have issues with resource files in library.zip.  Upgrading to a more recent version (as of this writing *18.3.1*) of `setuptools` appears to have fixed this issue (and dramatically decreased my start up time).